# Prevent landscape mode WinRT app when external keyboard connect

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, orientation, windows-rt

Our application supports only portrait mode and it is working fine.

But when I attach external keyboard for Microsoft Surface tablet, my application is converted to landscape mode.

Can I prevent this behavior to not to rotate to landscape even if external keyboard is attached?

I know it will not be good user experience, but my application is designed for portrait only, so when it rotated to landscape the UI looks very bad.

Thanks.

Comment: You could probably disable rotation managed by the OS, but it wouldn't make sense looking at it with a keyboard attached since you would need to tilt your head to see it straight. It might be a better idea to just implement landscape layout.